# PHP - How to convert multiple JSON-like strings to associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

**Input string:**

```
$times = '{endTime:"2017-03-29T17:15:00.000+11:00",startTime:"2017-03-29T17:00:00.000+11:00"},{endTime:"2017-03-31T17:15:00.000+11:00",startTime:"2017-03-31T17:00:00.000+11:00"},{endTime:"2017-04-01T12:15:00.000+11:00",startTime:"2017-04-01T12:00:00.000+11:00"}';
```

And I'm trying to convert it into an array that should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            endTime => "2017-03-29T17:15:00.000+11:00"
            startTime => "2017-03-29T17:00:00.000+11:00"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            endTime => "2017-03-31T17:15:00.000+11:00"
            startTime => "2017-03-31T17:00:00.000+11:00"
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            endTime => "2017-04-01T12:15:00.000+11:00"
            startTime => "2017-04-01T12:00:00.000+11:00"
        )

)
```

I've tried exploding, combining and all sorts but my code is so messy that I'm sure there must be a better and cleaner way?

This is **MY** cleanest starting point, but even this not clean, yes?

```
$times = '{endTime:"2017-03-29T17:15:00.000+11:00",startTime:"2017-03-29T17:00:00.000+11:00"},{endTime:"2017-03-31T17:15:00.000+11:00",startTime:"2017-03-31T17:00:00.000+11:00"},{endTime:"2017-04-01T12:15:00.000+11:00",startTime:"2017-04-01T12:00:00.000+11:00"}';
$timesarr = explode("},{", $times);

foreach ($timesarr as $i => $item) {
    $timesarr[$i] = str_replace("{", "", $item);
    $timesarr[$i] = str_replace("}", "", $timesarr[$i]);

    $timesarr[$i] = explode(",", $timesarr[$i]);
}


echo '<pre>'; print_r($timesarr); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: you tried `json_decode()`

Comment: i think the string is not a valid json, convert it to valid json first and then decode this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Improvements done:**

1. Appended square braces at `starting` and `end`.
2. Replaced words with `[a-zA-Z]+` with `"[a-zA-Z]+"` making it a valid `json` than `json_decode`

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/762463)

```
<?php

$times = '{endTime:"2017-03-29T17:15:00.000+11:00",startTime:"2017-03-29T17:00:00.000+11:00"},{endTime:"2017-03-31T17:15:00.000+11:00",startTime:"2017-03-31T17:00:00.000+11:00"},{endTime:"2017-04-01T12:15:00.000+11:00",startTime:"2017-04-01T12:00:00.000+11:00"}';
$times=$times."]";
$times="[".$times;
$jsonString=preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z]+\s*)\:/", '"$1":', $times);
print_r(json_decode($jsonString,true));
```

Comment: THAT is beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

This code will replace 'endTime' with '"endTime"' and same for startTime. I don't recommend you doing it this way, but it will work for you in this situation:

```
$times='{"endTime":"2017-03-29T17:15:00.000+11:00","startTime":"2017-03-29T17:00:00.000+11:00"},{"endTime":"2017-03-31T17:15:00.000+11:00","startTime":"2017-03-31T17:00:00.000+11:00"},{"endTime":"2017-04-01T12:15:00.000+11:00","startTime":"2017-04-01T12:00:00.000+11:00"}';
$times=str_replace("endTime",'"endTime"',$times);
$times=str_replace("startTime",'"startTime"',$times);
$times="[$times]";
echo "<h2><pre>";
print_r(json_decode($times,true));
```

This will output this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [endTime] => 2017-03-29T17:15:00.000+11:00
            [startTime] => 2017-03-29T17:00:00.000+11:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [endTime] => 2017-03-31T17:15:00.000+11:00
            [startTime] => 2017-03-31T17:00:00.000+11:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [endTime] => 2017-04-01T12:15:00.000+11:00
            [startTime] => 2017-04-01T12:00:00.000+11:00
        )

)
```

Comment: That works, but I don't have quotes on the keys on the incoming data?

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

First make the string a valid json string.

Add `[` at start and `]` at end. So your code will be

```
$times = '[{endTime:"2017-03-29T17:15:00.000+11:00",startTime:"2017-03-29T17:00:00.000+11:00"},{endTime:"2017-03-31T17:15:00.000+11:00",startTime:"2017-03-31T17:00:00.000+11:00"},{endTime:"2017-04-01T12:15:00.000+11:00",startTime:"2017-04-01T12:00:00.000+11:00"}]';

$result = json_decode($times, true);
```

Comment: `$times` is NOT a valid json.

Comment: @u_mulder not yet but he can make it to one!

Comment: Even with `[]` it still not a valid json. Please __test__ your code before answering.

Comment: the keys need to be enclosed with  doublequotes `""`

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid JSON, it looks like a bunch of JS variables concatenated together. You need a heavily customised parser:

```
<?php
$times = '{endTime:"2017-03-29T17:15:00.000+11:00",startTime:"2017-03-29T17:00:00.000+11:00"},{endTime:"2017-03-31T17:15:00.000+11:00",startTime:"2017-03-31T17:00:00.000+11:00"},{endTime:"2017-04-01T12:15:00.000+11:00",startTime:"2017-04-01T12:00:00.000+11:00"}';
$times = str_replace(["{","}"],["\0","\0"],$times); //replace {} with null bytes (they're hopefully unique and will be used as delimiters)

$csv = str_getcsv($times,",","\0"); //Treat string as a CSV enclosed in those null bytes

$csv = array_map(function ($v) {
    $vars = explode(",",$v);
    $arr = [];
    foreach ($vars as $var) {
        $parts = str_getcsv($var,":","\""); // endTime:"2017-03-29T17:15:00.000+11:00" is like a CSV split by : and enclosed in "
        $arr[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
    }
    return $arr;

},$csv);

print_r($csv);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [endTime] => 2017-03-29T17:15:00.000+11:00
            [startTime] => 2017-03-29T17:00:00.000+11:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [endTime] => 2017-03-31T17:15:00.000+11:00
            [startTime] => 2017-03-31T17:00:00.000+11:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [endTime] => 2017-04-01T12:15:00.000+11:00
            [startTime] => 2017-04-01T12:00:00.000+11:00
        )

)
```

Alternately walk away from this mess and demand your data be properly formatted as JSON.